# How to search for a value in a dictionary stored in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a monopoly like game and in this, I have a list which is for the players in this I have a dictionary for each player it is set up like this:

```
players.append[
{
   "playerName": John,
   "money": 1500,
   "properties": ["Mediterranean Ave"],
   "railroads": ["Reading Railroad"],
   "inJail":   False
}
{
   "playerName": Smith,
   "money": 1500,
   "properties": ["Baltic Ave"],
   "railroads": ["B. & O. Railroad"],
   "inJail":   False
}
]
```

so whenever a player lands on a property I want to check if anyone owns it and if anyone owns it who does, I tried using the count function but that did not work I also tried using the get function for dictionaries but that also failed what ways may I search for it.

Comment: Your players called and said they want to be a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
def is_property_owned(property_name):
    for p in players:
        if property_name in p['properties']:
            return p['playerName'] #Returns the owner of property
    return None # Returns None, if no one is owning it
```

Answer (score 0):

If this operation is going to be frequently executed, you may want to have another dictionary, say `props`, that describes who owns which property:

```
props = {}
for p in players:
    props.update({x: p['playerName'] for x in p['properties']})
```

Then finding the owner of a property is a matter of looking up in the dictionary:

```
owner =  props.get("Baltic Ave", None)
```

The dictionary must be updated every time the property changes the owner, e.g.:

```
props["Baltic Ave"] = "Smith"
```

Or:

```
del(props["Mediterranean Ave"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to retrieve a list of people owning a given property:

```
def property_owner(prop):
    return [dic['playerName'] for dic in players if prop in dic['properties']]

property_owner('Mediterranean Ave') # ['John']
property_owner('Whitehouse') # []
```